# ECharts custom legend hides line series labels when emphasis is applied

Tags: javascript, echarts

I've implemented custom legend for echarts that dispatches chart actions.
It works fine but sometimes it hides line charts labels.
To achieve that behavior you must click line1 button then line2 button to hide line charts. Then click them again in any order and at some point one of the lines on chart won't show it's labels.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Line Chart - Apache ECharts Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
  <div id="buttons">
      <button id="line1">line1</button>
      <button id="line2">line2</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
#buttons {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>

<script>
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

option = {
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'line1',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'self'
      },
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line'
    },
    {
      name: 'line2',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'self'
      },
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      data: [80, 150, 180, 250, 180, 160, 180],
      type: 'line'
    },
  ]
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);

const dispatch = (line) => {
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'legendToggleSelect',
    name: line,
  });
};

const mouseOver = (index) => {
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'highlight',
    seriesIndex: index,
  });
};

const mouseOut = (index) => {
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'downplay',
    seriesIndex: index,
  });
};

['line1', 'line2'].forEach((line, index) => {
  const item = document.getElementById(line);
  item.addEventListener('click', () => dispatch(line));
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => mouseOver(index));
  item.addEventListener('mouseout', () => mouseOut(index));
});
</script>
```

If emphasis option is removed from chart series then it works. But I need emphasis to higlight line on legend hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an unexpected and erratic behavior you discovered.

By logging the events on the chart and checking
what the true legend does, and after some debugging in the
source code, I identified what appears to be the problem:
a series that is highlighted, hidden and then shown again
produces two conflicting animations for the labels, one
for the normal rendering of the series to be displayed
and one for applying the `emphasis` state to the same.

Indeed, the problem doesn't manifest with animation disabled.

The solution is to dispatch a `downplay` event to the
series that is about to be hidden by legend selection, before
dispatching the `legendToggleSelect` event; this way all
hidden series will be in normal state. This action is
also performed by the true legend when a highlighted item
is clicked. And since a `downplay` sent to a hidden series
has no effect, the solution could be as simple as changing your
`dispatch` function to:

```js
const dispatch = (line) => {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'downplay',
        seriesName: line
    });
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'legendToggleSelect',
        name: line,
    });
};
```

```js
const dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
const myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
    renderer: 'canvas',
    useDirtyRect: false
});
const option = {
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
    //animation: false,
    animationDuration: 20,
    animationDurationUpdate: 20,
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'line1',
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'self',
            },
            label: {
                show: true
            },
            data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
            type: 'line'
        },
        {
            name: 'line2',
            emphasis: {
                focus: 'self',
            },
            label: {
                show: true
            },
            data: [81, 150, 180, 250, 180, 160, 180],
            type: 'line'
        }
    ]
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
    myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);

// myChart.on('legendselectchanged', data => console.warn('legend.select.changed', data));
// myChart.on('highlight', 'series.line', data => console.log('line.highlighted', data));
// myChart.on('downplay', 'series.line', data => console.log('line.downplayed', data));

const dispatch = (line) => {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'downplay',
        seriesName: line
    });
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'legendToggleSelect',
        name: line,
    });
};

const mouseOver = (index) => {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'highlight',
        seriesIndex: index
    });
};

const mouseOut = (index) => {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'downplay',
        seriesIndex: index
    });
};

['line1', 'line2'].forEach((line, index) => {
    const item = document.getElementById(line);
    item.addEventListener('click', () => dispatch(line));
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => mouseOver(index));
    item.addEventListener('mouseout', () => mouseOut(index));
});
```

```css
#chart-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#buttons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="line1">line1</button>
    <button id="line2">line2</button>
</div>
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
```